# Bypassing plt.show() automatically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following code to save multiple plots to individual files.

```
bench = ['AA', 'BB']
for b in bench:
    ...
    fname = b + '.png'
    plt.savefig(fname)
    plt.show()
```

Problem is that when I run the code, it brings up the plot for AA, then I have to close it and then it brings up BB. After closing the window, the program returns to prompt.

If I remove, `plt.show()`, the program terminates without "manual closing". However, in AA.png, I see only one line for AA, but in BB.png I see two lines, AA and BB.

Is there a way to bypass those "manually closing the plot windows"?

Comment: Have you tried `plt.draw()`  instead of `plt.show()`? And for the seeing of AA + BB in BB.png, do you clear your canvas (`plt.clf()`) before starting to plot for BB?

Comment: Right. They fixed the problem. Thanks,

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can close the post

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.draw()` instead of `plt.show()`

```py
bench = ['AA', 'BB']
for b in bench:
    # ... and maybe clear the plt here, plt.clf() to not mix AA with BB
    fname = b + '.png'
    plt.savefig(fname)
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: Even with draw, clf is required.